# Using Flow (Visual Workflow), is it possible to increase a custom date field by adding 'x' days in an assignment?

Tags: force.com, visual-workflow

I would like to use a Flow to perform a record update and increase a custom date field on a record by 365 days. In a good old SFDC formula field, you can do this easily by using a simple date formula like "custom_date__c + 365" and the date value will increase by 365 days.

Is it possible to do this using an Assignment in a Flow by updating the date from the record which is stored in a Flow variable?

FYI: the Flow needs to update the record because it will trigger or re-evaluate certain Workflow rules that are part of the custom logic/process so a WF field update or formula really won't work within the process context.

- The Flow is invoked through a custom button on record detail page.
- The custom date field is passed into the Flow through the URL and
  stored in a Flow variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the Assignment element. I did however have to read the custom date field within the Flow via the Lookup element, rather than passed in through a URL (any reason why you needed to do that?). I did try passing in the Date as you described in your question, but I got an internal Salesforce error. However I have achieved what you wanted I believe, here is how...

I created this flow...

[image]

And called it with this URL (from a Custom Button, behaviour no sidebar or header)...

```
/flow/namespace/UpdateDateBy365?RecordId={!Test__c.Id}&retURL=/{!Test__c.Id}
```

Using the Record lookup element I populated the DateToIncrease variable...

[image]

Using the Assignment element I increased it by 365...

[image]

Finally, using the Record Update element I updated it...

[image]

The reminder of the Flow simply displays the resulting value, when the user clicks the Finish button it redirects back to the URL passed in the 'retURL' parameter above.

Comment: Good to keep in mind that it's possible to add seconds/minutes/hours to DateTime fields by passing day division by time units e.g. 2 hours is 2/24

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use  record update and in filed value choose create new and formula. In the formula box write the below formula:

```
{!$Flow.CurrentDate} +30
```